# Unbound Local Error despite declaring the function variable as local

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have written a function that takes the input and converts it into hot_encoded_matrix, every time I try to run it, I am having the following error i.e.

```
       "/home/microbot/catkin_ws/src/spider/spider_control/control.py", 
       line 443, in one_hot_encoding
      return hot_encoded_matrix
      UnboundLocalError: local variable 'hot_encoded_matrix' referenced 
      before assignment
```

I have checked for every single variable used inside this function that whether it is global or local, all the variable are local.

```
def one_hot_encoding( iteration_time, model_type):
    a_1 = np.zeros((3, 1))
    if (model_type == 1):

        hot_encoded_matrix = np.insert(a_1, 0, 1, axis=0)#insert 1 in 
           the first column in x axis
    elif(model_type == 2):

        hot_encoded_matrix = np.insert(a_1, 1, 1, axis=0)
    elif(model_type == 3):

        hot_encoded_matrix = np.insert(a_1, 2, 1, axis=0)
    elif(model_type == 4):

        hot_encoded_matrix = np.insert(a_1, 3, 1, axis=0)
    else:
        print("please enter a valid model number")
    return hot_encoded_matrix
```

Here is how I am calling the function,

```
output = one_hot_encoding(run_time, model_trained)
```

run_time and model_trained being global variables

When it all works good, it must return a on_hot_encoding i.e. if the model trained is 1, then it should return an array like [1, 0, 0, 0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable is not assigned in the last `else:` branch.
I suggest to raise an exception is such a case:

```
raise ValueError(f"Value {model_type} is not a valid model number")
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick solution. This makes sense now.  I will try this and hope this works.